# Is $e$ uniformly distributed in all bases?

Tags: uniform-distribution, constants

There has been talk of whether or not $\pi$ is normal, i.e. uniformly distributed in all bases $b$ where $b\ge2$. The general response has been that we *expect* that it is, and have found no obvious counterexamples. Does the same apply to $e$?

Comment: Yes, exactly the same expectation and lack of knowledge there, though one might be a bit more suspiciuous about normality ...